# breadcrumbs_on_rails compatibility with Friendly ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, breadcrumbs, friendly-id

I'm using breadcrumbs_on_rails and Friendly ID in one of my projects.

```
def show
  @section = Section.friendly.find(params[:id])
  add_breadcrumb 'Introduction', section_path(@section)
end
```

This doesn't return an active link in the html, just plain text. Is there a workaround for this or am I just doing something wrong?

Just wondering if anyone had encountered this issue before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as described above worked for me. In fact the notation

`..., model_path(@modelinstance)`

was what I used to replace `..., :model_path`, which did *not* work with FriendlyId.

I am using: rails 4.2.6, breadcrumbs_on_rails 2.3.1, friendly_id 5.1.0